# how to catch all the errors in any scalatra action?

Tags: scala, scalatra

I am using scalatra to "export" a MongoDB data to JSon, my actions are very simple, like:

```
   get("/") {
      val title = db.get_collection("main", "api", "title")
      send_json(title)
    }
```

I want  to send a HTTP error and a text if something go wrong, on the other side it will be converted to something meaninful to the user. 
So the method becames:

```
   get("/") {
     try {
      val title = db.get_collection("main", "api", "title")
      send_json(title)
     } catch {
      case e:java.util.NoSuchElementException => send_error("DB malformed", InternalError)
      case e:com.mongodb.MongoException => send_error("Can not connect to MongoDB", InternalError)
      case e => send_error("Internal Error", InternalError)
    }
  }
```

The try catch is bigger that the actual method and I need to do this for every method, the class become at first sight an ugly collection of try catch. 
There is any way to avoid or minimize the bad looking and distracting try catch all over the code? I am new to Scala (and Java BTW) so I guess I am missing something.

I dont want the DB object to send JSON, so having the try catch on the db.get_collection method is not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I don't know Scalatra enough, but the `catch` block is a partial function, so you could do something like this:

```
val errorHandling: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = {
  case e:java.util.NoSuchElementException => send_error("DB malformed", InternalError)
  case e:com.mongodb.MongoException => send_error("Can not connect to MongoDB", InternalError)
  case e => send_error("Internal Error", InternalError)
}

get("/") {
  try {
   val title = db.get_collection("main", "api", "title")
   send_json(title)
  } catch errorHandling
}
```

Comment: my final solution was:
`val errorHandling: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = {`

If I use errorHandler, I got an error about that name to need to be override.
It also seemed to need java.lang.Throwable instead of Exception

Comment: @user1216071 Ok, I fixed the code accordingly, so others won't have to figure it out (if they happen to miss your comment).

Answer (score 46):

There's a special route handler for this:

```
error {
  case e: Throwable => {
    redirect("/")
  }
}
```

By changing the `case` statement you can switch on the error type.

Comment: This is the idiomatic method for handling errors in Scalatra, though it's missing from the documentation.